# Show or hide bands in GeoTIFF rasters (using QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, linux

I have a bunch of GeoTIFF images that show aerial photos of various fields. Bands 1-3 in these images contain the R/G/B components of the original photo. Bands 4-6 contain additional information about the pixels / raster cells in that image.

Now since I am a complete noob when it comes to GIS and GeoTIFF data, I am not sure how to handle these bands, how to show or hide them on top of the original RGB image. So I installed QGIS (I am working on Linux) and openend one of these TIFF raster images. The RGB photo is being shown correctly, but how can I show or hide the data from the additional bands 4-6?

Also maybe QGIS might be an overkill for me, as I am just looking for a (Linux) application, which I can use to view the GeoTIFF iamges and these  information in those additional bands. Do you have a recommendation for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose which bands to display under Symbology. Either singleband or multiband (RGB):
[image]

You can add the layer many times to table of contents to display all bands on top of eachother.